# Android: автоматический substr в ListView GmailApp

Tags: android, listview, java, gmail

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать автоматическое обрезание строк при выводе в `ListView`, как это сделано в приложении `Gmail`?

[image: gmail listview]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить для TextView свойство ellipsize = "end"